# Sitecore indexing a SXA Multisite configuration for more than 500 sites

Tags: sxa, solr, indexing

I am stuck with issue for indexing a SXA Multisite configuration for 600 sites. The case study is as below.

**Issue:** Indexing get failed at certain point of time from CM itself for Solr Master(after 2 million counters done)

**Details of the System:**

**Sitecore Version:** 8.2 Update 6

**SXA Version:** 1.6

**Solr Version:** 6.4.0 With Master Slave Configuration.

**Infrastructure:** Entire System is in premise with high Specification VMs

**Issue in Details:**

We have System which has Sitecore SXA implementation with above details.
This implementation has Multi site structure with 600 website right now in the System. When we are performing indexing (reindexing) It starts appropriately but at certain point of time after processing almost 2 millions counters it fails. I drilled down the logs but never got any exception for this it says timeout only, we also increase time out session to max but still the same.

After checking few things I found that if we increase the memory of Solr JVM then It will work that's why we increased memory to 5GB, still we are getting same issue.

Then after drilling down I found that we have only sitecore_master_index for CM and sitecore_web_index for CD in this SXA implementation. After drilling down few SXA indexing documentation I got below document for implementing different index(SOlr indexing core) for each SXA Multi Site/Language. But this Solution works with SXA 1.7.1 onward.

[Configure SXA indexing](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/configure-sxa-indexing.html)

But As I mentioned in the details we have SXA 1.6 Version.

So need a help how I can tackle this issue anybody cam suggest what is the best way of doing the indexing of huge application. Is the separate indexing core per site help or not if yes how I can implement in this scenario. Any other Solution which I can apply here. Or should I upgrade SXA version and then follow the document mentioned above.

Comment: 1.6 is a pretty old version, I strongly recommend upgrading to a more recent one. Later releases contain quite big amount of fixes and improvements (including search improvements).

Comment: @DawidRutkowski If I upgrade will it break everything implemented on the basis of 1.6, I mean I need to upgrade all the code libraries and custom code written around it.

Comment: What about a solution like the following: https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2019/10/28/dealing-with-very-long-running-search-builds/

Comment: You're gonna have to fix your broken architecture at some point. You should not have implemented anything so tightly locked to a specific SXA version and thereby abandoning your upgrade path.

Comment: @MichaelWest I tried this but still is failing, I think I will seat with team to redesign this.

Comment: Hi All, I am going to first upgrade and then redesign entire Solr Indexing, any suggestions, I am going to follow which I mentioned in question but any suggestions are welcome